# How to use regular expression on autocomplete

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer

This regular expression is a white list for allowable characters in a text field.  However, it doesn't catch the invalid characters when autocomplete is used to fill a field.

The shim at the end is used so IE and Edge can catch numpad invalid chars.

How can I get this regex to catch invalid chars when autocomplete fills?

```
var validChars = /^[ 0-9a-z\s.#,-]*$/i;
var textareas = document.querySelectorAll('.txt');
for(let i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++){
 textareas[i].addEventListener("paste", function(e){
var clipboardData, pastedData;
// Get pasted data via clipboard API
clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
var inputOk = scrub(pastedData);
if(!inputOk){
  e.preventDefault();
}
});
textareas[i].addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
  var inputOk = scrub(e.key);
  if(!inputOk){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
}
function scrub(contents)
      {

       if(contents.match(validChars))
         {
          return true;
         }
       else
         {
          alert("Invalid special character entered: " + contents + " ");
          return false;
         }
      }
// KeyboardEvent shim needed for Internet Explorer and Edge. These browsers return non-standard 'key' 
// property values from the numberpad. 
(function() {

  var event = KeyboardEvent.prototype
  var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(event, "key")
  if (!desc) return

  var keys = {

    Multiply: "*",
    Add: "+",
    Divide: "/",
  }

  Object.defineProperty(event, "key", {
    get: function() {
      var key = desc.get.call(this)

      return keys.hasOwnProperty(key) ? keys[key] : key
    },
  })
})()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use add an `input` event listener to the textarea and only allow the input if it matches the regular expression.

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<script>
var validChars = /^[ 0-9a-z\s.#,-]*$/i;
var prevInput = null;
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener("input", function(e){
  if(!this.value.match(validChars)){
    alert("Invalid Input!");
    this.value = prevInput? prevInput: '';
  }
  prevInput = this.value;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! But, this works well on the first of the six total fields, but it doesn't throw the alert on invalid character detection.  In addition, any fields other than the first one also do not clear the text field contents on invalid char detection. The alert will pop open, but the invalid contents remain.  I tried to write in a sequential "for" loop, but no luck. Anything i can change here?

Comment: @Jupitar You have six textareas?

Comment: yes, but I'll have some pages where there may be more.

Comment: @Jupitar Use a `for` loop to iterate through all of the textareas and add the same event listener.